# WPF Usercontroll - Itemsource (enum) of Combobox is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to bind an enum to a combobox in a WPF-Usercontrol. I already got the different enum-values in, but the binding to my viewmodel doesn't work.

My Usercontroll:

```
UserControl
x:Class="XpTimeWriter.UserControls.FooterBar"
x:Name="me"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:XpTimeWriter.Enums"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XpTimeWriter.UserControls"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="80"
d:DesignWidth="800">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider
        x:Key="EnumDescription"
        MethodName="GetValues"
        ObjectType="{x:Type enums:Filter}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="enums:Filter" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
 <ComboBox
        Width="100"
        DockPanel.Dock="Right"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumDescription}}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFilter, ElementName=me}"
         />
...
```

The dependencyproperty behind:

```
 public Filter SelectedFilter
    {
        get { return (Filter)GetValue(SelectedFilterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedFilterProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedFilter.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedFilterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedFilter", typeof(Filter), typeof(FooterBar), new PropertyMetadata(Filter.All));
```

My Binding-Property:

```
private Filter _filter;
public Filter SelectedFilter
    {
        get => _filter; 
        set
        {
            SetProperty<Filter>(ref _filter, value);

            this.WorkTimes = LoadList(_filter);
        }
    }
```

The SetProperty-Method from my ViewModelBase:

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value, Action onChanged = null, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
```

The enum:

```
 public enum Filter
{
    All,
    LastWeek,
    CurrentWeek,
    FromTo
}
```

It seems as if the getter is working but on changes of the itemsource the setter is never executed.

Comment: You mean when you select an item in the ComboBox, the SelectedFilter property in the view model is not set? Make sure the Binding on the UserControl property is declared TwoWay. You may also register the dependency property so that it binds TwoWay by default.